# ORACLE SQL: Looping over table

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I have a table that contains a list of table names. 
I would like to search each of these tables one by one to see if they contain a particular element (the primary key, specified at the start of the script). 
I would like to return a list of all of the tables that this element is present in (ideally distinct).
I'm fairly new to this PL/SQL "not just a query" stuff. so i apologise in advance for the attrocious attempt you are about to see, but hopefully it illustrates what i'm going for:

```
PROCEDURE CHECK_FOR_ELEMENTS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
ELEMENT_KEY varchar(5):=X78ehryfk;
RNUM_MAX int :=167;

----create output table for script
create or replace table ALL_TABLES CONTAINING_&ELEMENT_KEY 
(ELEMENT_KEY VARCHAR(255), 
TABLE_NAME varchar(255))
/
commit;

---begin loop over rnum;
FOR rnum_counter in 1..&RNUM_MAX
LOOP
--define this statement as variable TABLE_NAME_VAR
select table_name from (select * from (select table_name, rownum as rnum         
from all_tables
where owner = 'RMS'
and table_name like 'ABC%'
and table_name not like '%STG'
and table_name not like '%BKP'
and num_rows>0
order by num_rows desc)
where rnum = rnum_counter
)INTO TABLE_NAME_VAR
;
----run below to collect row, if it exists, from table being searched
SQL_STMT:='INSERT INTO ALL_TABLES CONTAINING_&ELEMENT_KEY 
SELECT distinct key,'||TABLE_NAME_VAR||' as UMF from         
'||TABLE_NAME_VAR|| 
' where key like 'ELEMENT_KEY-%'
execute immediate SQL_STMT;
commit;
---insert row into table created for output

END LOOP
---loop over all tables

END;
```

The main error message i get is that TABLE_NAME_VAR is not a valid table name within the dynamic SQL statement. I've googled a bit and i now understand you can't use variables to input table names in this way.

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thankyou!

Comment: what happens if ou just run the select statement alone, I assume generates the error? SELECT distinct voyage_key,'||TABLE_NAME_VAR||' as UMF from         
'||TABLE_NAME_VAR||

Comment: Yes, i get the following error message :
    ORA-00903: invalid table name
    00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:

Comment: don't like this approach at all, but you'd need to use execute immediate and build up the DDL string inside your procedure.

Comment: @tbone, thanks, i dont like my approach either as it doesnt work. but my limited knowledge of SQL is very much to blame im sure. I'm sorry im not really sure what a DDL string is but i'll google it and see what i get.

Comment: DDL is Data Definition Language, basically your "create table" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I tried to clean it up for you. Let me know if you still get errors.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CHECK_FOR_ELEMENTS is
    ELEMENT_KEY varchar2(14):='X78ehryfk';
    RNUM_MAX int :=167;
    TABLE_NAME_VAR varchar2(30);
    SQL_STMT varchar2(4000);
BEGIN

----create output table for script
begin
    execute immediate 'drop table ALL_TABLES_WITH_' || element_key;
exception when others then null;
end;
execute immediate 'create table ALL_TABLES_WITH_' || element_key || ' 
(ELEMENT_KEY VARCHAR2(255), -- does this need to be 255 characters?
TABLE_NAME varchar2(30))';

--- implicit cursor loop
FOR rnum_row in (select table_name, rownum as rnum         
    from all_tables
    where owner = 'RMS'
    and table_name like 'ABC%'
    and table_name not like '%STG'
    and table_name not like '%BKP'
    and num_rows>0
    order by num_rows desc)
LOOP
    if rnum_row.rnum > RNUM_MAX 
        then exit;
    end if;

    TABLE_NAME_VAR := rnum_row.table_name;

    ----run below to collect row, if it exists, from table being searched
    SQL_STMT:='INSERT INTO ALL_TABLES_WITH_' || element_key || ' 
    (ELEMENT_KEY, TABLE_NAME)
    SELECT distinct key, :1 as UMF from         
    '||TABLE_NAME_VAR|| 
    ' where key like :2';
    execute immediate SQL_STMT using TABLE_NAME_VAR, element_key || '-%';

    ---insert row into table created for output
END LOOP;
commit; 
---loop over all tables

END CHECK_FOR_ELEMENTS;
/
```

Comment: Given that `element_key` is defined as `VARCHAR(255)` there's a good chance that `ALL_TABLES_WITH_' || element_key` will violate Oracle name length limits (even if using Oracle 12cR2 extended name capability.

Comment: Yes good point. OP defines it as a `varchar2(5)` (which is too small for the given string), so I edited and changed it to varchar2(14), since anything larger than that will violate the basic 30 char name limit using a prefix of `ALL_TABLES_WITH_`.

Comment: THANKYOU! It compiled! :D 
Only problem now is how to access the table containing the results....it says the table does not exist when i try to query it afterwards. @kfinity

Comment: Well, you can `select * from user_tables` to search for it. Are you running the procedure after compiling it? `exec check_for_elements;`

Comment: I was looking at the column declaration in the `create table` statement. But your code is valid.